# neo4j collecting nodes and relations type b-->a<--c,a<--d

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am extending maxdemarzi's excellent graph visualisation example (http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/07/03/the-last-mile/) using VivaGraph backed by neo4j.

I want to display relationships of the type

```
a-->b<--c,b<--d
```

I tried the query

```
MATCH p = (a)--(b:X)--(c),(b:X)--(d)  
RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | {id:ID(n), name:COALESCE(n.name, n.title, ID(n)), type:LABELS(n)}) AS nodes,  
EXTRACT(r in relationships(p)| {source:ID(startNode(r)) , target:ID(endNode(r))}) AS rels
```

It looks like the named query picks up only `a-->b<--c` pattern and omits the `b<--d` patterns.

Am i missing something... can i not add multiple patterns in a named query?

Comment: Please share your results when you are finished !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most immediate problem is that the comma in the MATCH clause separates the first pattern from the second. The variable 'p' only stores the first pattern. This is why you aren't getting the results you desire. Independent of that, you are at risk of having a 'loose binding' by putting a label on both of your nodes named 'b' in the two patterns. The second 'b' node should not have a label.

So here is a version of your query that should work.

```
MATCH p1=(a)-->(b:X)<--(c), p2=(b)<--(d)
WITH nodes(p1) + d AS ns, relationships(p1) + relationships(p2) AS rs
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN ns | {id:ID(n), name:COALESCE(n.name, n.title, ID(n)), type:LABELS(n)}) AS nodes,
       EXTRACT(r in rs| {source:ID(startNode(r)) , target:ID(endNode(r))}) AS rels
```

Capture both paths, then build collections from the nodes and relationships of both paths. The collection of nodes actually only extracts the nodes from p1 and adds the 'd' node. You could write that part as

```
nodes(p1) + nodes(p2) as ns
```

but then the 'b' node will appear in the list twice.

Comment: I had a very similar answer in mind :). And, I also think that the second path is not necessarily needed, since it is only one relationship that could be added itself to the others, like: `... b<-[r_d]-d ... rels(p) + r_d`. It would also be more symmetric.

Comment: @zaboco can you elaborate your answer? How would you add (a)-->(b:X)<--(c),(b)<--(d) in to one? (without adding a comma)

Comment: @Zahoor sorry, I guess I didn't explain myself well enough: I did not mean that the two paths could be added into one, I just said that I would change `p2=(b)<--(d)` into `(b)<-[r_d]-(d)` and `relationships(p1) + relationships(p2)` into `relationships(p1) + r_d`. That's because `relationships(p2)` is equivalent to `[r_d]` (p2 is an one-relation path)